# VueJs - loading dynamic images

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Here is my code which is works as charm as possible:

```
        <li class="icon-list">
          <img src="../assets/apple.svg" alt="apple" class="icons">
        </li>        
        <li class="icon-list">
          <img src="../assets/google.svg" alt="google" class="icons">
        </li>
```

I want to do above with dynamic loop. so I've used v-for and using `:src` and `:alt`.

```
    <li v-for="icon in icons" class="icon-list">
      <img class="icons" :src="'../assets/' + icon.src" :alt="icon.alt">
    </li>


export default {
  name: "Home",

  data() {
    return {
      icons: [
        {          
          src: "google.svg",
          alt: "google"
        },
        {          
          src: "apple.svg",
          alt: "apple"
        }
      ]
    };
  }
};
```

However it does not load any images. Any suggestion?

Comment: did you try `:src="require('../assets/' + icon.src)"`?

Comment: @BoussadjraBrahim Yes , and still does not load, after :src="require('../assets/' + icon.src)" I'll have a URL like this for image: http://localhost:8080/assets/google.svg . everything seems well but it does not work

Comment: there're some errors?

Comment: Not at all, is it depends on my localhost or what? when I use static <li> I have a URL like this : data:image/svg+xml;base64,PHN2ZyB4 instead of  localhost:8080/assets/google.svg

Comment: I think with `src` webpack parse the image to base64 instead of a url, while with `:src` he doesn't because it is getting parsed by vue to a URL, do you have a static public folder in your root path `/assets/` with the images in it? and also the fact that there are no errors is weird, you should see the image or get an error that the image path return 404 code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know what you are trying to achieve isn't possible the way you imagine it to be. Vue templates only have access to attributes of the associated component model **at runtime**.
However, webpack will bundle all assets, including images, first **at compile time**.

When binding `:src="'../assets/' + icon.src"` the app will try to find it relative to the url context of the browser, which depending on where you put your files and which server you use could be anywhere.

What you can do is importing the files using webpack, which will give you a base64 representation of the image and bind that to the source like so:

`import Logo from '@/assets/logo.png'`

```
export default {
  name: "App",
  data() {
    return {
      sources: [Logo]
    }
  }
};
```

and then bind it like this:

```
<img v-for="(source, index) in sources" :key="index" width="25%" :src="source">
```

I've made [an example](https://codesandbox.io/s/53w3n50o6k), in case that helps. Caveat: this is probably not a very good solution for large file sizes.